# How can I get the correct value of INSERT after 'BackSpace' striked in Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, text

The value of INSERT will be changed after pressing the BackSpace key, but I got the old position. How can I get the action-after position.

For example:

Th|is is a book.

"|" is the cursor, and the value of INSERT is 1.2

When BackSpace pressed, I got a 1.2 firstly in event handler of , then the cursor moved to 1.1

The same, when I typed This is a book
`T => 1.0, h => 1.1, ......,` I think it should be `T => 1.1, h => 1.2, ......`

There are lot of Keys to change the cursor position, I cannot get the final position to reduce INSERT always by 0.1

Is there any way to get the final position ? or the  handler can work after Text widget ?

```py
from tkinter import *

def action(event):
    print(event)
    position = t.index(INSERT)
    print(position)

root = Tk()
t = Text(root)
t.bind('<Key>', action)
t.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

expect: 1.1
actual result: 1.2

Answer (score 2):

This is because the event `'<Key>'` is triggered before the key effect is processed. Events directly bound to the widget always occur before class events, and the edition of the text in the widget is a class binding to the keyboard.

What you want is a binding to `'<KeyRelease>'`, which will be triggered after the key is processed:

```
from tkinter import *

def action(event):
    print(event)
    position = t.index(INSERT)
    print(position)

root = Tk()
t = Text(root)
t.bind('<KeyRelease>', action)
t.pack()

root.mainloop()
```